# Hide a particular instance of a repeating component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table with an ngFor iterating over a collection. For each item in the collection it will produce a row containing a single cell. The cell contains a button and custom component. The custom component has an ngIf directive which only shows the custom component if the device is deemed to be online. I'd like to be able to toggle the visibility of the custom component by clicking the button also. How do I pass the ***particular instance*** of the custom component in the table cell to the onExampleBtnClick() function? I do not wish to show/hide all instances of the custom component, only the one that shares the cell with the clicked button. Thanks

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let item of items;let indexOfelement=index;">
  <td>
    <button type="button" (click)="onExampleBtnClick($event)" #ExampleButton>Click Me</button>
    <custom-comp *ngIf="showIfDeviceOnline"></custom-comp>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `item` is a variable in scope, just like it would be in a normal `for(){...}`. Is it not enough to pass that to your event handler?

Comment: You can wrap your custom component inside an ng-container and apply the ngIf condition at that level.

Comment: @Mike S, item has no relation to my custom-component.I use it simply to display the text in a seperate cell that I removed for simplicity sake of my example.

Comment: @Vimal Patel, how do I create an ngIf condition that will apply to the particular ng-container in the same cell as the clicked button and not all the others that are repeated on the page?

Comment: @Fred2020 I have added the answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

You can create another property on your data array which will keep track of if the component need to be shown or not. You dont need to touch existing data creating a new array of object using map function like below.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  Items:string[] =  ['Apple','Oranges'] ;
  data: any  = null;
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.data = this.Items.map(x=> {
      return {
          name: x,
          show:true
      }
    });
  }
  
  hide(item){
    item.show = false;
  }
}
```

and based on that you can apply ***ngIf**  condition on container like below.

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.show">
      <button type="button" (click)="hide(item)"> Click Me</button>
      <app-custom></app-custom>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-forest-871qc?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:160-449

Another approach is the create a mapper object which will keep track of status of each item of array and based on the status hide the component.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Your code seems to address a different problem though. Using your example, I'm trying to hide the <app-custom> that appears directly after the button, and only hide the custom component, when the button is clicked. This example wraps everything in an ng-container and hides everything when the button is clicked.

Comment: If you only want to hide the component not the button then wrap the ng-container around your component only and then component will show/hide on button click. I have update the code accordingly, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Local references is what I was looking for. I can wrap the custom component in a div and apply a local reference of #CustComp and then pass CustComp to the onExampleBtnClick function. It will reference the actual instance and allow me to target it's hidden property.